# quickbook API python getToken

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I am trying to get some data from the quickbook API in python.
I don't want (for now) to integrate it in a website I just want some Json with data on my company.
I already have the token from the website but i'm trying to get it throught python.

```
auth_client = AuthClient( client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, environment )

Scopes = [Scopes.ACCOUNTING]
url = auth_client.get_authorization_url(Scopes)

print(url)
```

This code give me the url : https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=XXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.intuit.com%2Fv2%2FOAuth2Playground%2FRedirectUrl&state=XXXX

The next step according to the documentation of quickbooks will be to do :

```
auth_client.get_bearer_token(auth_code, realm_id=realm_id)
```

My problem is that I don't know **where to find the auth_code** (I want to get it with python not on the intuit pages)

The documentation from quickbook says :

> Redirect your users by browser to the url generated above. After user connects to the app, the callback >URL has params for state, auth_code and realm_id (realm_id for Accounting and Payments scopes only).*

But I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with the URL

Comment: did you click link which you get? I will guess: It may redirect you to page which will ask if program can access your data and then page will give you `auth_code` which you have to copy to code and then code will have access to your data. In all APIs it looks this way.

Comment: you have to get `auth_code` only once so it is simpler to get it manually. Most APIs are created to work with web pages and they use web page to generate `auth_code` and it is easy to use it when you write web server with Python but when you try to use it in console or desktop GUI then it makes problem - it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser or GUI widget which can display web page.

Comment: The link I get redirect me to an error webpage : "This website can't be reach"

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm going to try Selenium

Comment: when you register Application then you may have to decide if it will be web page or desktop application. For web page you have to add url on your page and it will send `auth_code` to this page. If you defined non-existing page then you get `"website can't be reach"`. For desktop application you should set `localhost` and it will display code in web browser. Using Selenium will not help you if you have wrong settings.  Besides you have to run it only once to get `auto_code` and writing special code for one person is waste of time. Code can be useful when you have web page used by many users.

Comment: Which kind of "token from the website" you have? I think that this is only credentials to "your quickbooks-app". But do you have connection/auth_token between "your quickbooks-app" and your python script?